# Android view pager with SQlite

Tags: android

I'm trying to displaying images in view pager and that view pager as row in List View . When i run the application My emulator is getting crash and getting error .Please see my log cat here.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 4 Pager id: com.example.tazeen.classnkk:id/pagerMyPics Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.example.AdapterClasses.ViewPagerAdapter
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:999)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.widget.GridLayout.measureChildWithMargins2(GridLayout.java:1004)
            at android.widget.GridLayout.measureChildrenWithMargins(GridLayout.java:1014)
            at android.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:1055)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1944)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1857)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1344)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1684)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:562)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2114)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I don't understand where my code is wrong .i'm getting all row images in this imageArray and passing this imageArray  to holder.view_pager.

```
 if (!(vp_adapter == null))
                {
                    vp_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.view_pager.invalidate();
                    vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageArray);

                    holder.view_pager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
                    holder.view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);

                }
                else
                {
                    vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageArray);

                    holder.view_pager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
                    holder.view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);

                }
```

Here is ViewPager adapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String png_Pattern = ".png";
    String jpg_pattern = ".jpg";
    String bmp_pattern = ".bmp";
    String gif_pattern = ".gif";
    String jpeg_pattern = ".jpeg";
    String mp3_Pattern = ".mp3";

    ArrayList<String> imgArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imgArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imgArray = imgArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgArray.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontalitem , container,false);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_AllPost);

        String strImage = imgArray.get(position);
        if (strImage.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_placeholder);
        }
        if (strImage.endsWith(png_Pattern) || strImage.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || strImage.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || strImage.endsWith(gif_pattern) || strImage.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_placeholder);
        }
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue with notifyDataSetChange.

Here is my ListAdapter Code

```
 class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<All_Post> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<All_Post> data = new ArrayList<All_Post>();
        private DisplayImageOptions options;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<All_Post> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;

            dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(context);
            dbhelper.onOpen(db);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

            final Holder holder;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.allpostlist, parent, false);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.text_ActivityId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textActivityId);
                holder.text_InspectorName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textInspectorName);
                holder.text_SpChar = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textSpChar);
                holder.text_Notation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textNotation);
                holder.txtViewDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_Date);
                holder.txtInitialLetter = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_InitialLetter);
                holder.txtRemark = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textRemark);

                holder.txtFollowUpCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.count_txtFollowUp);
                holder.txtCameraCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.count_txtImages);
                holder.txtAudioCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.count_txtAudio);

                holder.imgBtn_FollowUp = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButton_FoloowUp);
                holder.imgBtn_RateEquipMent = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonRateEquipment);
                holder.imgBtn_Camera = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButton_Camera);
                holder.imgBtn_Audio = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButton_RecordAudio);
               // holder.gallery = (Gallery)row.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
                holder.view_pager = (ViewPager)row.findViewById(R.id.pagerMyPics);
                //holder.horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) row.findViewById(R.id.hlist);
                //holder.lLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.innerlay);

                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
            }


            final All_Post all_Post = data.get(position);
            holder.text_ActivityId.setText(all_Post.getStrActivityId());
            holder.text_InspectorName.setText(all_Post.getStringInspectorname());

strListItem_ActivityId = all_Post.getStrActivityId();


            /*******************************************************Start******************************************************************/
            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList where activityId ='" + strListItem_ActivityId + "'", null);
            imageArray.clear();
            audioCount.clear();
            imageCount.clear();
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    count = cursor.getCount();

                    do {
                        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));

                        if (imagePath.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                        {
                            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            String path = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + imagePath;
                            File file = new File(path);
                            long length = file.length();
                            length = length / 1024;

                            if (length > 0)
                            {
                                Log.e("", "");
                                imageArray.add(imagePath);
                                audioCount.add(imagePath);

                            }}

                        if (imagePath.endsWith(png_Pattern) || imagePath.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || imagePath.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || imagePath.endsWith(gif_pattern) || imagePath.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                        {
                            String strBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            String filepath = strBaseDir + "/classnkk_images/" + imagePath;

                            File file = new File(filepath);
                            long length = file.length();
                            length = length / 1024;

                            if (length > 0)

                            { imageArray.add(imagePath);
                                imageCount.add(imagePath);}
                        }
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    cursor.close();

                }
  if (!(vp_adapter == null))
                {
                    vp_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.view_pager.invalidate();
                    vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageArray);

                    holder.view_pager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
                    holder.view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);

                }
                else
                {
                    vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageArray);

                    holder.view_pager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
                    holder.view_pager.setCurrentItem(1);

                }
 return row;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @p.Id can you post your complete listview's adapter code over here?Because that will help in understanding the issue with your vpageradapter initialization code.

Comment: Thanks for reply !!. Ok just minute .

Comment: @Droidwala : I have post  listview's adapter code , please see above in my post.

Comment: @p.Id where are values added to imageArray in your code?

Comment: Sorry ? But i don't understand your question

Comment: I mean to ask about imagearray defined in this line `vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageArray);`.. where are values getting added in this/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96332/discussion-between-p-ld-and-droidwala).

Answer (score 0):

Exception just simply means that  getCount() changed and you didn't send NotifyDataSetChanged. Adapter checks it quite often and if you read database and don't notify your adapter each time you modify your collection it's no wonder that you receive this exception.

In order to fix the issue instantiate new list before you read you db. Read it to your list. 1. Set new list to your adapter (with notify adapter call) or 2. create a new adapter.